# Problem mapping Fluent NHibernate One-To-Many

Tags: database, orm, nhibernate, mapping, fluent

I am having issues mapping two classes to a database via Fluent NHibernate.
My classes are `Asset` and `LogData`.

`Asset` has a bunch of decimal configuration values, and a Log which is a `LogData`.

```
public class Asset
{
    public virtual int AssetID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } = "New Asset";
    public virtual double Value1 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value2 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value3 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value4 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value5 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value6 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value7 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value8 { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public virtual double Value9 { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<LogData> Log { get; set; } = new List<LogData>();
}
```

`LogData` has a bunch of decimal values for what it has measured, and a timestamp.

```
public class LogData
{
    public virtual Asset Parent { get; set; } = new();
    public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value1 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value2 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value3 { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object? obj){...}
    public override int GetHashCode(){...}
    }
}
```

Here is my `Asset` Map

```
public AssetMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.AssetID,"AssetID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable().Default("\'New Asset\'");
        Map(x => x.Value1).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value3).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value4).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value5).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value6).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value7).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value8).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value9).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Log)
            .AsBag()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .KeyColumn("AssetID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
```

And my `LogData` Map

```
public LogDataMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Parent, "AssetID")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Timestamp);
        Map(x => x.Value1).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value2).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Value3).Not.Nullable();
    }
```

When I start my application, the first thing that happens is a
`SchemaValidator().Validate()` is run, which discovers that the `Asset` and `LogData` tables do not exist, and calls a `SchemaUpdate.Execute(false, true)`. The Schema Update encounters an exception though:

```
{"Invalid collection name: 'Foreign Keys'. (Parameter 'collectionName')"}
```

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of. I have tried removing the `Asset` reference from the `LogData`'s Composite ID and just having it as a `References`, I have tried removing all mapping settings from `Asset`'s `HasMany`, heck, I have tried entirely removing all references between the `Asset` and the `LogData` and just treating them as entirely separate tables with no knowledge of each other, but every time the end-result is that same exception; it catches the same invalid Foreign Keys collection, even if the entire database model has NO foreign keys whatsoever.

With these kinds of errors, typically, the answer is that I am missing something obvious, but it'll take a different pair of eyes than mine to see it. Help?

Comment: i cant reproduce the error with the code posted. Are you sure it is these 2 classes? Also i would recommend mapping Logdata as Component

Comment: Those two are the only two classes that I persist, so I would have to assume those are the issue.
I do not see what benefit there would be in mapping LogData as a component, as I want it to be a separate table, both for the volumes, but also because it is accessed from outside the database by the real-world asset. Perhaps I am misunderstanding how components work?

Comment: I meant in the collection as component `.AsSet().Component(m => { m.ParentReference(x => x.Parent); m.Map(x => x.Timestamp);...})`. Also i wouldn't new() up the Parent

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, because the issue was something else: The table name, "Asset". I could not tell you why, but when I changed the name "Asset" to "Test", it worked. I should note that this may be an issue specific to the type of Database I use, which I should have mentioned is MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the name of the table "Asset".
I have no idea why, this may be an issue specific to MariaDB, or it may be something to do with NHibernate.

Regardless, the problem is solved.